# The sum of a telescoping series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I proof that the sum of

$$1- \frac12 + \frac13 - \frac14 +\frac15 -\, \dots$$

up to $\infty$ is $\ln(2)$?

How can I calculate it using the telescoping method?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

It is not a telescopic series. You can sum it using the Taylor expansion
$$
\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}{n}=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\dots,\quad|x|<1.
$$
The series is convergent when $x=1$ and $\ln(1+1)=\ln2$. To justify that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=\ln2
$$
you can use [Abel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem).

Comment: @JonathanY. The answer includes your observation and a link to Abel's theorem.

Comment: Oh dear, I expected the link to point to Abel's criterion for convergent series and (foolishly) haven't bothered to check. Apologies. (I +1-ed, but if I may suggest, some justification/reference for the analyticity of $\ln(1+x)$ in $(0,1)$ may help.)

Answer (score 3):

There is a trick that consists in remarking that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-2\sum_{k=1}^{[n/2]}\frac{1}{2k},$$

where $[.]$ is the floor function. Basically you sum all terms $\frac{1}{k}$ and you substract twice the terms of the form $\frac{1}{2k}$.

You can then conclude using the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=\ln(n)+\gamma+o(1).$